# How do I tell Cordova to not auto-hide the splash screen?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I've got the following in my config.xml...

```
  <feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="false" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen"       value="false" />
  <preference name="SpalshScreenDelay"          value="60000" />

  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"   gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"   gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png"  gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"  gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"  gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />

  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
```

When I open the application on a device, I see the splash screen... but it closes on its own, I'm not calling any javascript to close it. It should just say up, forever.

This is what I see in the device logs:

```
Jul 15 17:04:41 iPad-5 TRAF[2615] <Warning>: Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
Jul 15 17:04:41 iPad-5 TRAF[2615] <Warning>: Unlimited access to network resources
Jul 15 17:04:41 iPad-5 TRAF[2615] <Warning>: Fix applied for database locations?: YES
Jul 15 17:04:41 iPad-5 TRAF[2615] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][file] 5.380988ms
Jul 15 17:04:41 iPad-5 TRAF[2615] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 27.823985ms
Jul 15 17:04:41 iPad-5 TRAF[2615] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 37.027001ms
Jul 15 17:04:41 iPad-5 TRAF[2615] <Warning>: Resetting plugins due to page load.
Jul 15 17:04:43 iPad-5 TRAF[2615] <Warning>: Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/662EC33F-CC74-42C4-83F0-4D4EC759EF80/TRAF.app/www/index.html#/
```

I don't want the splash screen to close, until I tell it to. So everything I'm reading the way I have the config.xml is should work, yet... nada.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add SplashScreen plugin?

Comment: or Are you doing this on Android?

Comment: @AsankaIndrajith - org.apache.cordova.splashscreen is in the config.xml listed above. This is on iOS at the moment but will need to work on Android as well.